# How to add my own plugin to IE, so that if I visit the webpage, IE should ask for installation of that plugin

Tags: html, internet-explorer, plugins, activex

I will get a plugin to be installed when i go to this path.

```
http://www.axis.com/files/developer/camera/AXISMediaControlSDK_6_06.zip
```

But using this, I have to install the plugin in each computer that uses this control.
But I want the people using my webpage should be asked for to install by IE automatically,when they access the webpage.
I've used the following code

```
<object id="Player" width="250" border="1" style="margin-top:10px"
        classid="CLSID:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B">
<param name="pluginspage" value="http://www.axis.com/files/developer/camera/AXISMediaControlSDK_6_06.zip" />
</object>
```

But using above code, it doesn't ask for the software to get installed. Can anybody please help me in solving this problem using html or java script or php?

Comment: This is the code i used in my php file.                       <object id="Player" width="250" border="1" style="margin-top:10px"
  classid="CLSID:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B">   <param name="pluginspage" value="http://www.axis.com/files/developer/camera/AXISMediaControlSDK_6_06.zip" /></object>                                              But this code doesn't seems to work

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the codebase property of the object element? e.g.

```
<object id="Player" width="250" border="1" style="margin-top:10px"
classid="CLSID:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B" 
codebase="http://www.axis.com/files/developer/camera/AXISMediaControlSDK_6_06.zip">...</object>
```

Some Edimax IP cameras are using it in their web interface and it's working.